# How to access a mapping variable which is a struct from another contract.?

Tags: solidity

```
contract C1 {
   Struct S1 {
     bool v1;
     string v2;
   }
   
   Struct S2 {
     bool v3;
     string v4;
     S1 v5;
     mapping(uint => S1) v6;
  }
  
  mapping(string => S2) public products;
}

contract C2 {
  C1 contract1;
  
  Constructor(address _add){
    contrac1 = new C1(_add);
  }

  function printProducts(){
    // Incomplete code
    contract1.products["sample"];
  }

}
```

How do i access C1 variable called `products` inside C2 function `pintProducts()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can access a public property with its getter. In the case of products it will be like this:

```
  function printProducts() public {
    (bool v3, string memory v4, C1.S1 memory s) = contract1.products("sample");
  }
```

For backward compatibility structs are returned as a tuple, removing mappings and dynamic arrays.